# Laravel: Column 'category_slug' cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'category_slug' cannot be null (SQL: update `products` set `category_slug` = ?, `products`.`updated_at` = 2022-12-23 12:06:26 where `id` = 1)

How I get product category_slug colmun from category slug table.

Categories Table:

|id|name|slug |
|4 |Cat4|cat-4|
|5 |Cat5|cat-5|
|6 |Cat6|cat-6|

Products Table

|id|name|category_id|category_slug|
|1 |USDT|4          |cat-4        |
|2 |BTCH|5          |cat-5        |
|3 |EURT|6          |cat-6        |

**Product Controller** (Update Method)

```
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:190',
            'price' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
        ])->validate();

        $code=Product::find($request->id);
        $code->name=$request->name;
        $code->category_id=$request->category_id;
        $code->category_slug=$request->category_slug;
    $code->update();

        return redirect()->back()->with('success',__('Product has been updated'));
    }
```

`

**Product Model**

`

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::class,'id','category_id');
    }
```

`

I GET THIS ERROR

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'category_slug' cannot be null (SQL: update `products` set `category_slug` = ?, `products`.`updated_at` = 2022-12-23 12:06:26 where `id` = 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here :

```
$code->category_slug=$request->category_slug;
```

It seems that $request->category_slug is null/undefined. If you are sure sending it from the frontend via an input make sure it has the right name attribute name="category_slug"

If however, you don't send it from frontend you should use [slug helper](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-slug) to generate it from a string you chose, example:

```
$code->category_slug= \Str::slug($request->name . '-' .$request->category_id);
```

This will generate a slug from the name and id combined.

**EDIT**: If you want to get the current Product category slug you can use it like so:

```
$code->category_slug=$code->category->category_slug;
```

You might need to use $code->save() instead of update()

Comment: I think your question is about getting category slug from the product, I've edited the answer

Comment: Thx bro this what I need

`$code->category_slug=$code->category->category_slug;
`

Comment: Glad that helped you, You can accept this answer (if you find it helpful) by clicking on the big gray check button on its left side. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not add the `category_slug` to your products table

you already have all the information you need about the product's category when you added the `category_id` to the `products` table

to get the `category_slug` from the product

you can do something like this

```
Product::with('category')->find(1)->category->slug
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your migration.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('category_slug')->nullable()->change();
    });
}
```

It seems that you are not sending any value to the `category_slug` column while updating the record. The column must have a `nullable` constraint.

Comment: but my question is, how can I get category_slug from categroy table to product table with category_slug colmun

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. The error is pointing out your `update` query

Comment: And I don't know if it `$code->update();` works fine. I think you should use `$code->save();` instead

Comment: I mean category_slug is foreign not string